# menu change page information

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onchange

I'm trying to have multiple dropbox menu's on the same page that will change the information on the next page after submitting their selection.

so the user can make different and multipule selections from the menus then click "submit" and different information will be on the next page and not the same page like the script below.

this is the closest thing ive found but trying to get the information on the next page instead is proving tricky.

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Person 1</td>
      <td>Information</td>
      <td>
        <select id="choice1" onchange="changeText('choice1', 'display1')">
          <option>Select</option>
          <optgroup label="Category 1">
            <option>G1 Choice1</option>
            <option>G1 Choice2</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="Category 2">
            <option>G2 Choice1</option>
            <option>G2 Choice2</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Person 2</td>
      <td>Information</td>
      <td>
        <select id="choice2" onchange="changeText('choice2', 'display2')">
          <option>Select</option>
          <optgroup label="Category 1">
            <option>G1 Choice1</option>
            <option>G1 Choice2</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="Category 2">
            <option>G2 Choice1</option>
            <option>G2 Choice2</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr> 
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="display1">Select an option</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="display2">Select an option</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
<script>
var textBlocks = [
  'Select an option',
  'G1 Choice1 description',
  'G1 Choice2 description',
  'G2 Choice1 description',
  'G2 Choice2 description'
];

function changeText(elemid, displayId) {
  var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex;
  document.getElementById(displayId).innerHTML = textBlocks[ind];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

POST data is sent to the server and not returned to the client. This means that your JavaScript code will never see what was submitted.

You either need to do whatever you want server-sided (i.e., in PHP) or you need to change the way you send and read data (i.e., via hash part of the URL, via cookies,...). Using a server-side language is most likely a better option, although it does depend on what you are trying to achieve.